# Proportion (difference) test for drifting proportions

Tags: time-series, proportion

Two machines are spitting out coins (at different non-constant rate). The probability of flipping heads for every machine is believed to change very slowly in time (compared to flipping rate). It is also quite low (less than one in a thousand, say).

What kind of test would suggest that the machines currently (within certain time window in the past) have equal probabilities? That they have probabilities differing by more than X? Same two questions for certain time window in future.

It seems logical that one cannot use the usual methods for testing proportions with constant probabilities. Would just censoring the observations to the time window of interest and then applying the usual proportion test be a reasonable approach? How could one incorporate the information from observations falling out of this window (which subjectively seems valuable)? Should I look in the direction of Kalman filter/dynamic Bayesian networks?